# Where to place views and templates that use information from multiple apps in the project?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to figure out general guidelines for arranging views/templates in a django project with multiple apps so that the apps remain fairly re-usable.

For specific example:
I have a django project with three main apps:
- `accounts`: That manages user account related stuff
- `reports`: That generates reports
- `courses`: That manages course contents

I also have a `\templates` directory in the project, and have three directories under it corresponding to each of the three apps. This breakdown works well for me on pages that deal with individual app elements.

However, there are views and pages where I need to show information collected from all three apps. For example, I might want to show an overview page with the User payment status (accounts), his past reports(reports) and his current course(course).

I understand that apps must be kept as independent as possible. What are the guidelines for  place views/templates that do not clearly belong to one app but import from different apps? Should I create a project-specific app just to hold these views/templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how re-usable you need to make these shared templates. I often just put these sorts of templates into a "shared" directory. Sometimes I'll have a "shared" that applies to the entire project, and sometimes I'll have one that is shared within an app. It just depends on what works best for you.

Comment: @Brabdon and @okm, do you mean that you create a directory `shared` or `common` under the project and store the views and templates there? Another option I was thinking of was to create three separate app-specific templates and then just load them in the one template to render. And do similarly for views. That way the templates (and views) actually remain independent. But that seems just a complex way of doing things.

Comment: For templates that are specific to only one project, but shared across multiple apps, like say, an include that renders Messages from the messages framework, I'll just create a folder called "shared" in my Templates directory. For views, models, etc, that are shared, I create an app module called "lib".